# Advantages of Restlet as a standalone application?

Tags: java, restlet

It is quite easy to configure restlet to run as a standalone java application.

However I am wondering what the advantages are as opposed to deploying into a container like tomcat or jetty?

The main issue I have is one of stability and availability: a container is usually run as a service that is monitored by the OS and for example restarted on boot etc. For a standalone application I would have to create monitoring and startup services myself.

Are there specific use-cases in which a standalone application would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I can think of is that a standalone application is more lightweight and needs somewhat less configuration.

Secondly I found it very useful when testing, because it is easy to start up within a junit environment.